# Extjs Grid prevent childtap after childlongpress

Tags: extjs

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2vt6

On grids a after a **childlongpress** event a **childtap** event is also fired.

Is there a simple way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

I made `workaround` for your problem.

I compare the `tap` point, if the `tap` is the same as `longpress`, I reject it.

```
var userStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    data: [{
        name: 'Lisa',
        email: 'lisa@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-111-1224'
    }, {
        name: 'Bart',
        email: 'bart@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-222-1234'
    }, {
        name: 'Homer',
        email: 'homer@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-222-1244'
    }, {
        name: 'Marge',
        email: 'marge@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-222-1254'
    }]
});
var last_point = null;
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Grid', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    store: userStore,
    width: 400,
    height: 200,
    title: 'Application Users',
    listeners: {
        childtap: function (a, b, c, d) {
            if (Ext.encode(b.event.touch.point) != last_point) {
                console.log("child tap");
            }
            last_point = null;
        },
        childlongpress: function (a, b, c, d) {
            last_point = Ext.encode(b.event.touch.point);
            console.log("childlongpress Event")
        }
    },
    columns: [{
        text: 'Name',
        width: 100,
        sortable: false,
        hideable: false,
        dataIndex: 'name'
    }, {
        text: 'Email Address',
        width: 150,
        dataIndex: 'email',
        hidden: true
    }, {
        text: 'Phone Number',
        flex: 1,
        dataIndex: 'phone'
    }]
});
```

Example on fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3021&view/editor